# compose/transporter migrate data from mongodb to elasticsearch with different mapping for each document

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch

I have a collection in mongodb where each document is a graph. Document schema is different for each document. Each document has following arrays as its keys

`nodeAttrs` : array of objects, each representing details of an attribute of node

`nodes`: array of nodes containing attributes defined in nodeAttrs

`edgeAttrs`: array of objects, each representing details of an attribute of edge

`edges`: array of edges containing attributes defined in edgeAttrs

Now the challenge is that any of these 4 properties can be null for a document, but most of the time they are populated. However, the schema of objects in these arrays is different across documents. For some graphs, edges may have different attributes than other graphs. Similarly with nodes.

I am using [compose/transport utility](https://github.com/compose/transporter/) to migrate the data from mongoDB to elasticsearch. I want to dump each record to a separate type in the destination (with different mapping). Anybody tried that lately ?

Here is an example of elements of edgeAttrs, and edges arrays:

Here are the edgeAttrs:

```
"edgeAttrs" : [ 
  {
    "id" : "LinkTypeNum",
    "title" : "LinkTypeNum",
    "generatorType" : "file",
    "generatorOptions" : null,
    "_id" : ObjectId("539dd0a62a91d09735264ae7"),
    "visible" : true
  }, 
  {
    "id" : "LinkType",
    "title" : "LinkType",
    "generatorType" : "file",
    "generatorOptions" : null,
    "_id" : ObjectId("539dd0a62a91d09735264ae6"),
    "visible" : true
  }, 
  {
    "id" : "In Minimal Spanning Tree (c)",
    "title" : "In Minimal Spanning Tree (c)",
    "generatorType" : "file",
    "generatorOptions" : null,
    "_id" : ObjectId("539dd0a62a91d09735264ae5"),
    "visible" : true
  }
]
```

And here is a edges array containing just one edge. The attrs array of edge contains the attributes defined in edgeAttrs plus a weight attribute. Similar structure is present for nodeAttrs and nodes with a lot more attributes.

```
"edges" : [ 
  {
    "id" : "0",
    "source" : "76",
    "target" : "1",
    "_id" : ObjectId("539dd0a62a91d09735262f33"),
    "attr" : [ 
      {
        "id" : "weight",
        "val" : "1.0",
        "_id" : ObjectId("539dd0a62a91d09735262f37")
      }, 
      {
        "id" : "LinkTypeNum",
        "val" : "3",
        "_id" : ObjectId("539dd0a62a91d09735262f36")
      }, 
      {
        "id" : "LinkType",
        "val" : "Non-Feeding Positive",
        "_id" : ObjectId("539dd0a62a91d09735262f35")
      }, 
      {
        "id" : "In Minimal Spanning Tree (c)",
        "val" : "false",
        "_id" : ObjectId("539dd0a62a91d09735262f34")
      }
    ],
    "visible" : true,
    "layerId" : 0,
    "label" : "edge"
  }
]
```

Comment: From reading the docs I think it's a straight mapping 1 collection 1 index.  I am raising a support ticket to find out and will post back the results.